# Can't get Facebook Friends in my Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to get Facebook Friends list to populate a Spinner object.Actually I can't seem to get the friends list at all and have been digging all over the place to get this to work. Using code found here early I have tried to get things to work with no luck.Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.Below are the pieces of code that pertain to this! At the moment I am not even trying to populate the spinner since I don't seem to be getting what I need. My List friends ends up having nothing in it with which to populate the spinner.

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Session s = (Session) extras.getSerializable("facebookSession");

        if ((s!= null && s.isOpened()))
        {
            Log.d("FacebookSession", " is not null and is open");

        }
        else if ((s != null && !s.isOpened()))
        {
            Log.d("FacebookSession", " is not null and is not open");
        }
        else if (!(s != null))
        {
            Log.d("FacebookSession", " is null");
        }
        Session.setActiveSession((Session) extras.getSerializable("facebookSession"));
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        SessionState state;
        boolean i = session != null && session.isOpened();
        String l;
        if (i) { l = "true"; }
        else { l = "false"; }

        Log.d("Logged in", l);
        if (i)
        {
            Log.d("tagging", "trying to get data");
            getUserData(session, session.getState());
            requestMyAppFacebookFriends(session);
        }
    }
```

Session is valid and ultimately works in my getUserData function call to populate user id and profile pic.

```
private Request createRequest(Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture"};
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

    Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
    parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
    request.setParameters(parameters);

    return request;
}

private void requestMyAppFacebookFriends(Session session) {
    Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
    friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            List<GraphUser> friends = getResults(response);
            // TODO: your code here
            int x = friends.size();
            Log.i("List of Friends size -> ", "" + x);

        }
    });
    friendsRequest.executeAsync();
}

private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
    GraphMultiResult multiResult = response
            .getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
    GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
    return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
}
```

the Log.i("List of Friends size -> ", "" + x); outputs to log cat size zero

```
11-12 03:22:37.352    4300-4300/mobileapps.*************** I/List of Friends size ->﹕ 0
```

Please help

Comment: the easy solution is read the Facebook API documentation first.It clearly states that you can't get the friend list straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per new Facebook APIs one cannot get the friends list unless a friend authorizes your app. It is still possible to retrive friends list only if one uses older version of Facebook APIs/sdk..Hope this helps..I am able to successfully list my friends using older versions of facebook apis..

Comment: the older api's will stop working from dec 25 i guess.So its not worth trying

Comment: Got it going, only my friends/co developers appear.... but I guess that better then nothing, It ended up being a permissions issue primarily!!! thanks guys!!!!...... is there a workaround to get a full friends list that you know of Anirudh? ya know, as opposed do just calling me a noob and playing down someone elses suggestion???? (which was valid but will lose access soon)

Comment: So ask the ones whom you want to see in friend list to authorize your app :-)

Comment: v1.0 of the api will still work until end of april 2015. anyway, the answer is correct, +1. there is no workaround, this is for privacy reasons. you should not get data of anyone who did not authorize your app.